# Appending column values into new cell in the same row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a csv file that has columns `name`, `sub_a`, `sub_b`, `sub_c`, `sub_d`, `segment` and `gender`. I would like create a new column `classes` with all the classes (`sub`-columns) seperated by comma that each student takes.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

The result dataframe should look like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| name | sub_a | sub_b | sub_c | sub_d | segment | gender | classes             |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| john | 1     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1       | 0      | sub_a, sub_b, sub_d |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| mike | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 0       | 0      | sub_a, sub_c, sub_d |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| mary | 1     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1       | 1      | sub_a, sub_b, sub_d |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| fred | 1     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0       | 0      | sub_a, sub_c        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post that excel as text here? Blanket copy and paste then format it as a code block

Comment: @Datanovice I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `dot`

```
s=df.filter(like='sub')
df['classes']=s.astype(bool).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

Comment: It is my bad that I forgot to indicate that my dataframe has columns that has 0-1 values. How could I handle that?

Comment: @tacoisdelicious do filter before dot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`

For Ex.: if your dataframe like

```py
df
   A_a  A_b  B_b  B_c
0    1    0    0    1
1    0    1    0    1
2    1    0    1    0
```

you can do

```py
df['classes'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df.columns[x==1]), axis = 1)
df
   A_a  A_b  B_b  B_c   classes
0    1    0    0    1  A_a, B_c
1    0    1    0    1  A_b, B_c
2    1    0    1    0  A_a, B_b
```

To `apply` on specific columns you can filter first using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
#for your sample data
df_ = df.loc[:,'sub_a':'sub_d']             #or df.loc[:,'sub_a', 'sub_b', 'sub_c', 'sub_d']
df_.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df_.columns[x==1]), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Hey @Dishin, what if I have other columns that has 0-1 values too, I forgot to indicate that. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed want to iterate through the rows. However, you can not directly add the classes to the DataFrame as all columns of the DataFrame need to be equally long. So the trick is to first generate the column and then add it later:

```py
subjects = ['subj_a', 'subj_b', 'subj_c']
classes_per_student [] # the empty column

for _, student in df.iterrows():
    # first create a list of the classes taken by this student
    classes = [subj for subj in subjects if student[subj]]
    # create a single string
    classes = ', '.join(classes)  
    # append to the column under construction
    classes_per_student.append(classes)

# and finaly add the column to the DataFrame
df['classes'] = classes_per_student
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` only on the `sub`-columns to apply a lambda function that will join the names of the `sub`-columns where the values of the columns equal 1:

```
sub_cols = ['sub_a', 'sub_b', 'sub_c', 'sub_d']
df['classes'] = df[sub_cols].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df[sub_cols].columns[x == 1]), axis=1)
```